# How can I maintain some file differences between my local and the remote repository in Git?

Tags: git

I made some changes to my local clone of a repository and committed them in a local branch. Let's call these changes "commit A". I want to keep working on top of commit A, but when I'm ready to merge back into the main branch I don't want commit A merged.

I'm thinking I can use `git rebase -i` and delete commit A, but is there a way to keep that commit alive, so that future work can be done on top of it? And then, again, the work merged back to the main branch without commit A.

I realize that what I'm doing is a bit sketchy, but the lines changed in commit A are orthogonal to the work on top of it. The changes are related to differences between machines (production and testing) because they must reference different versions of a third-party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking I can use `git rebase -i` and delete commit A, but is there a way to keep that commit alive, so that future work can be done on top of it? And then, again, the work merged back to the main branch without commit A.

You can tag it. The commit deleted from the branch will not be gone. And then later when you need it, you can cherry-pick the tag. That is:

```
git tag somename SHA1
...
git rebase -i OLDREV
...
git cherry-pick somename
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, maybe this:

Create two branches, one with the changes for Prod one with changes for Testing.  Then your workflow would go like this:

```
1) Pull updates
2) Create a local working/topic branch
3) Merge from Test branch
4) Do your work, test, etc.
5) When ready to push back, first merge from Prod branch
6) Merge back into your main/develop/master branch
7) Push
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in that situation is stash the changes in commit A (not commit them). That way, any time I want to work with those changes, I apply the stash (see below), but as long as I don't commit them, I don't need to worry about them ending up on the remote. This is easiest if the files changed in A are not the same as the ones you are working on.

To set this up now, assuming A is the last commit on your branch.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

And later:

```
git stash list
git stash apply stash@{n}
```

`git stash list` is to find `n`

Comment: This will work, but there are two reasons I don't prefer it personally.  (1) You have to be careful not to accidentally commit the stashed changes, which may create extra work at random points in your workflow.  (2) I just don't like long-lived stashes; which I guess I wouldn't care about if I didn't also use short-lived stashes quite a bit, but since I do I find the long-term ones get in my way.  But ymmv

Answer (score 1):

Before I get to my answer:  I would recommend approaching the root problem (needing different code on a different machine) in a more formalized way, as I suspect this is eventually going to cause you more trouble.  Depending on languages and tooling I recognize that may not be easy (and certainly I can't offer a generic solution without knowing languages, tooling, etc.), but you may find it worth it.

But hey, assuming your current approach is going to work fine for you, here's how you'd make it stick:

You start with this situation

```
X --- X <--(origin/master)
       \
        A --- B --- C <--(master)
```

You want to push changes form `B` and `C` but not `A`; and further, you want locally to continue working based on all changes from `A`, `B`, and `C`.

To make things run as smoothly as they can, you'll also want git to realize that changes from `B` and `C` are taken care of, so that later (when you have `D` and want to push it) you don't end up doing a bunch of pointless conflict resolution.

So first do your interactive rebase; but instead of removing `A`, move it to the end of the TODO list.  After this operation you should have

```
X --- X <--(origin/master)
       \
        B' --- C' --- A' <--(master)
```

(Technically A, B, and C are still hanging around, and you could get back to them if you need to; but if all goes well, you won't need to.)

Now you want to back `master` up a commit, push, then pull `master` back to `A'`.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

yielding

```
X --- X --- B' --- C' <--(origin/master)
                     \
                      A' <--(master)
```

carry on, repeat as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rebase --onto` to rebase everything up to (but not including) A. The [rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) has good examples of using `--onto` that match the scenario you're describing. Essentially you would do:

```
git rebase --onto master A
```

If you don't want the current branch to be rebased (because you want to keep working on it later) then just check out a new temporary branch first:

```
git checkout -b new-temporary-branch
git rebase --onto master A
```

Then fast-forward master to the new branch by merging it into master.